# Ajax can not connect to the server on android device with cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am trying to retrieve data from the server using ajax with json format , while I'm running in the web browser data to appear , but when it is run on android device connection problems?

This my html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/card.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/custom.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kc.fab.css" />

    <title>samplingApp</title>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/list_pm.js"></script>        
        <script src="js/kc.fab.min.js"></script>    

    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header">
            <a href="index.html" rel="external" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide"> back</a>
                <h1>Project List</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <ol data-role="listview" id="listview">
                <li data-role="list-divider" style="text-align: center;"><h1>Microbe</h1></li>
                </ol>                       

                <div id="pesan"> 
                    <div class="main-container">
                      <div class="fixer-container" style="text-align:center;">
                      <p>Koneksi bermasalah</p>
                        <div class="koneksioff" style="text-align:center;">
                        <a target="_blank" href="menu_microbe.html" type="button" data-role="button" data-icon="refresh" data-iconpos="notext"/></a>                
                        </div>      
                      </div>
                    </div>                  
                </div> 
                <a target="_blank" href="insert_pm.html"  data-transition="fade" data-transition="fade" class="kc_fab_wrapper"></a> 
            </div>  
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

This list_pm.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var links = [
        {
         "bgcolor":"red",
         "icon":"+",
         "title": "add"
        }
      ]
    $('.kc_fab_wrapper').kc_fab(links);     

    //var getData="http://bbicpretest.esy.es/json.php";
    document.getElementById("pesan").style.display = 'none';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        //url: "http://localhost/book/json_pm.php",
        url: "http://samplingtrial.esy.es/json_pm.php",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(){$.mobile.loading('show');},
        timeout: 3000,
        error: function(){
            //$("#pesan").popup('open');
                $.mobile.loading('hide');
                document.getElementById("pesan").style.display = 'block';
                //document.getElementById("cari").style.display = 'none';
                // will fire when timeout is reached
                //alert('ada kesalahan');
            },              
        success: function(result){
            var result=$.parseJSON(result);
            $.each(result, function(i, element){        
                var id_pm=element.id_pm;
                var nama_project=element.nama_project;  
                var lokasi=element.lokasi;
                var tanggal=element.tanggal;
                $("#listview").append("<li><a href='sampling_pm.html?id_pm="+id_pm+"&nama_project="+nama_project+"&lokasi="+lokasi+"&tanggal="+tanggal+"' rel='external'><h2>"+ nama_project + "</h2></a></li>");   
                $('#listview').listview().listview('refresh');
                $.mobile.loading('hide');
                document.getElementById("pesan").style.display = 'none';
            }); 
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Thanks @Pramod, yes there is an error in the connection to the server

Comment: post error or logcat.

Comment: I can not check logcat , because an error occurs in the android device , if I run in the browser no problem

Comment: which device are you using?? Marshmellow?

Comment: You can debug your cordova app using Chrome and paste the log here. You can follow this guide to set it up: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging

Comment: @Pramod i using kitkat

Comment: @DevidFarinelli thanks for the advice

Comment: @dwiyanto you're welcome, are there any news on the topic?

Comment: Can you post your app's config.xml also, and which version of cordova are you using... what does `cordova --version` output?

Comment: solved my problem, why ajax is not connected to the server for `< uses- permission android : name = " android.permission.INTERNET " / >` is not written in AndroidManifest.xml